# Word2Vec - How to rid of "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'" and "AttributeError: dlsym(0x7fa8c57be020, AttachDebuggerTracing): symbol not found"?

Tags: gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

Getting `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` and `AttributeError: dlsym(0x7fa8c57be020, AttachDebuggerTracing): symbol not found` errors when I create my model based on `Word2Vec` implementation of the `gensim` module.

**Each entry has three parts** which are presented within a list. And, **the model contains three entries** for the sake of demonstration.

Here is what I have tried:

```
model = Word2Vec(sentences=features, size=100, sg=1, window=3, min_count=1, iter=10, workers=Pool()._processes)

model.build_vocab(features)

model.train(features)
```

The value of the `features` is:

```
  [
    [
      ['permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE', 'permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE', 'permission.READ_PHONE_STATE', 'permission.INTERNET', 'permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE'],
       ['intent.action.MAIN', 'intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED_ACTION', 'intent.action.SIG_STR', 'intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED'],
       []
    ],
    [
      ['permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE', 'permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE', 'permission.READ_PHONE_STATE', 'permission.INTERNET', 'permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES', 'permission.SEND_SMS', 'permission.DELETE_PACKAGES'],
      ['intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED', 'intent.action.USER_PRESENT', 'intent.action.PHONE_STATE', 'intent.action.MAIN'],
      []
    ], 
    [
      ['permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE', 'permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION', 'permission.INTERNET', 'permission.READ_PHONE_STATE', 'permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION', 'permission.CALL_PHONE', 'permission.READ_CONTACTS', 'permission.READ_SMS'], 
      ['intent.action.PHONE_STATE', 'intent.action.MAIN'], 
      []
    ]
  ]
```

**Edit:** The error stack trace after correcting the form of the feature vector according to the comment of @gojomo.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1631, in settrace
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1631, in settrace
2019-12-13 12:24:34,519:gensim.models.base_any2vec:INFO - worker thread finished; awaiting finish of 3 more threads
2019-12-13 12:24:34,519:gensim.models.base_any2vec:INFO - worker thread finished; awaiting finish of 2 more threads
2019-12-13 12:24:34,519:gensim.models.base_any2vec:INFO - worker thread finished; awaiting finish of 1 more threads
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1631, in settrace
2019-12-13 12:24:34,519:gensim.models.base_any2vec:INFO - worker thread finished; awaiting finish of 0 more threads
2019-12-13 12:24:34,520:gensim.models.base_any2vec:INFO - EPOCH - 10 : training on 6 raw words (0 effective words) took 0.0s, 0 effective words/s
    stop_at_frame,
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1711, in _locked_settrace
2019-12-13 12:24:34,520:gensim.models.base_any2vec:INFO - training on a 60 raw words (2 effective words) took 0.1s, 21 effective words/s
    stop_at_frame,
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1711, in _locked_settrace
2019-12-13 12:24:34,520:gensim.models.base_any2vec:WARNING - under 10 jobs per worker: consider setting a smaller `batch_words' for smoother alpha decay
    stop_at_frame,
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1711, in _locked_settrace
    debugger.enable_tracing(apply_to_all_threads=True)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 482, in enable_tracing
    debugger.enable_tracing(apply_to_all_threads=True)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 482, in enable_tracing
    pydevd_tracing.set_trace_to_threads(self.dummy_trace_dispatch)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd_tracing.py", line 241, in set_trace_to_threads
2019-12-13 12:24:34,521:gensim.utils:INFO - saving Word2Vec object under model/word2vec_model, separately None
    pydevd_tracing.set_trace_to_threads(self.dummy_trace_dispatch)
    debugger.enable_tracing(apply_to_all_threads=True)  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd_tracing.py", line 241, in set_trace_to_threads

  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 482, in enable_tracing
    pydevd_tracing.set_trace_to_threads(self.dummy_trace_dispatch)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd_tracing.py", line 241, in set_trace_to_threads
    result = lib.AttachDebuggerTracing(
      File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 361, in __getattr__
result = lib.AttachDebuggerTracing(
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 361, in __getattr__
    result = lib.AttachDebuggerTracing(
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 361, in __getattr__
2019-12-13 12:24:34,521:gensim.utils:INFO - not storing attribute vectors_norm
        func = self.__getitem__(name)func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 366, in __getitem__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 366, in __getitem__

2019-12-13 12:24:34,522:gensim.utils:INFO - not storing attribute cum_table
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 366, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))AttributeError: dlsym(0x7fed18f247e0, AttachDebuggerTracing): symbol not found

AttributeError: dlsym(0x7fed18f247e0, AttachDebuggerTracing): symbol not found
func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1631, in settrace
AttributeError: dlsym(0x7fed18d2ff70, AttachDebuggerTracing): symbol not found
    stop_at_frame,
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1711, in _locked_settrace
2019-12-13 12:24:34,524:gensim.utils:INFO - saved model/word2vec_model
    debugger.enable_tracing(apply_to_all_threads=True)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 482, in enable_tracing
    pydevd_tracing.set_trace_to_threads(self.dummy_trace_dispatch)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd_tracing.py", line 241, in set_trace_to_threads
    result = lib.AttachDebuggerTracing(
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 361, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 366, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: dlsym(0x7fed18a163b0, AttachDebuggerTracing): symbol not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1631, in settrace
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1631, in settrace
    stop_at_frame,
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1711, in _locked_settrace
    stop_at_frame,
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1711, in _locked_settrace
    debugger.enable_tracing(apply_to_all_threads=True)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 482, in enable_tracing
    debugger.enable_tracing(apply_to_all_threads=True)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 482, in enable_tracing
    pydevd_tracing.set_trace_to_threads(self.dummy_trace_dispatch)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd_tracing.py", line 241, in set_trace_to_threads
        pydevd_tracing.set_trace_to_threads(self.dummy_trace_dispatch)
result = lib.AttachDebuggerTracing(  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd_tracing.py", line 241, in set_trace_to_threads

  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 361, in __getattr__
    result = lib.AttachDebuggerTracing(
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 361, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 366, in __getitem__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 366, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: dlsym(0x7fed15fd5850, AttachDebuggerTracing): symbol not found
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: dlsym(0x7fed18a163b0, AttachDebuggerTracing): symbol not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1631, in settrace
    stop_at_frame,
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1711, in _locked_settrace
    debugger.enable_tracing(apply_to_all_threads=True)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 482, in enable_tracing
    pydevd_tracing.set_trace_to_threads(self.dummy_trace_dispatch)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd_tracing.py", line 241, in set_trace_to_threads
    result = lib.AttachDebuggerTracing(
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 361, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 366, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: dlsym(0x7fed18b09320, AttachDebuggerTracing): symbol not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1631, in settrace
    stop_at_frame,
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1711, in _locked_settrace
    debugger.enable_tracing(apply_to_all_threads=True)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 482, in enable_tracing
    pydevd_tracing.set_trace_to_threads(self.dummy_trace_dispatch)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd_tracing.py", line 241, in set_trace_to_threads
    result = lib.AttachDebuggerTracing(
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 361, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 366, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: dlsym(0x7fed15fd5850, AttachDebuggerTracing): symbol not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gensim's `Word2Vec` expects its corpus `sentences` to be a *sequence* where each individual item is a *list of string tokens*. (That is, those string tokens are words.)

Instead, you have a list (which is acceptable as a sequence), where each of its items is a list (which is also acceptable), but then each of those lists instead has as each item yet another *list* – when for `Word2Vec` training, each of those items should be a string token (word).

(I've edited your example data to be be structurally-indented, to make the levels of nesting clearer.)

If those innermost lists-of-strings are your real individual "sentences", you need to be sure they're the items in your outermost list.

(If, on the other hand, you really want a cluster like `['intent.action.PHONE_STATE', 'intent.action.MAIN']` to be a single "word" in your model, you'll want to change that list into a single string token, so it can look like a word – and thus hashable key – to `Word2Vec` and Python.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have corrected the structure according to your comment (I change the innermost `lists-of-strings` to `strings`). Now, getting various `AttributeError: dlsym(0x7fa2fc101750, AttachDebuggerTracing): symbol not found` errors. And despite these errors, the execution finishes as I print the model as the last command. I got this output: `Model has 6 entities and 100 vectors`.

Comment: I don't recognize that `AttributeError`, so if it's a concern, you should show a full stack trace of these errors *after* the `unhashable type: 'list'` error has been eliminated. (It seems likely to be an artifact of your PyCharm-based interactive execution environment, and if they're displaying but then training still completes, they seem like they may be debugging output about ignorable errors that are not related to your data or gensim models.)

Comment: Please see the edited OP as I have added the new error stack trace.